# How can i show the data in specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i want to show an output to a specific cell at B column but i really don't have any idea on how to make it to show. Example: if "A2" has the record i want "B2" to show the output. If "A100" has the record, i want "B100" to show the output

```
Sub Testing()

  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Range("A2:A4")
    If cell.Value = "yes.com" Then
      Range("B2:B4").Value = "Correct"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

The code above shows the output data "Correct" from "B2" to "B4" but what i want it to show on only the specific cell. Please Help

Comment: `cell.offset(0,1).value = "Correct"`. But it can all be done a bit smarter. Would you need to iterate a lot of rows? Or really just this little rows?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. yes i need to iterate around 1000 rows. may you advise me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are looping through a range object. Per cell. One a small dataset this is fine but in your current attempt you'll need to change:

`Range("B2:B4").Value = "Correct"` for `cell.Offset(0,1).value = "Correct"`

As per my comment, you can do this a bit smarter/faster. Looping through worksheet cells is slow, certainly on large datasets (a 1000 rows is not that many yet to be honest). Nonetheless it's good to know that a good practice is to go through arrays. Let me show you below:

```
Sub Testing()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:B" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(x, 1) = "yes.com" Then
            arr(x, 2) = "correct"
        End If
    Next x
    .Range("A2:B" & lr).Value = arr
End With

End Sub
```

So you can see a few things that will be helpfull:

- A reference to a sheet (through a `CodeName` to refer to a range's parent. Without it, the macro will simply reference the `ActiveSheet` which is for obvious reasons not always the correct one.
- I have made use of a dynamic sized array. The `lr` variable will get the last used row in column A, so you don't have to work through full qualified references no more.
- The `arr` variable is an array which takes the values from the specified range into memory. Running through data in memory is much quicker than a loop/iteration over worksheet cells. This will become much more noticable when you would have even larger datasets.
- I wrote the array back to the range in one go instead of several writings.

Hopefully that helped =)

---

As previously mentioned a 1000 rows is still not that much. Allthough I suggest you stick with the `Array` approach, you can also `Evaluate` column A and fill column B accordingly in one go instead of stepping through a range object. It's an array formula in disguise so not very quick on actual large datasets.

```
Sub Testing()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A2:B" & lr)
    rng.Columns(2).Value = .Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Columns(1).Address & "=""yes.com"",""correct"","""")")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
Sub test()
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1) = "yes.com" Then Cells(i, 2) = "Correct"
  Next
End Sub
```

It will loop through entire `A` column.

Alternatively, you can enter in B1 formula:

```
=IF(A1="yes.com","Correct","")
```

and drag it all the way down.

Comment: Up-voting for the formula suggestion as I think that is the better route in this particular case.